# Paramiko can't get output for grep command

Tags: python, linux, paramiko

I am using a `paramiko` library.

Using `shell = ssh.invoke_shell()` and `shell.send()`.

The command i am sending is `cmd = """grep -i "Lost LLUS websocket" /var/log/debesys/cme.log\n"""`.

But i am not getting output .

I am using `shell.receive` to get the output but i always get blank.I have tested the command manually and it works fine.Does anybody have any idea on how to get the output?

Comment: Did you check stderr for errors and the exit status?

Comment: Did you mean using `shell.recv(bytes)` to get the output? Can you get results if you run some general command say `ls`?

Comment: Can you post your actual code? Also, have you looked into using exec_command() instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works exactly the way you want it, but only going off the question title, here's how I would do it if you wanted to send the grep command itself:

```
def run_cmd(sshClient, command):
    channel = sshClient.get_transport().open_session()
    channel.get_pty()
    channel.exec_command(command)
    out = channel.makefile().read()
    err = channel.makefile_stderr().read()
    returncode = channel.recv_exit_status()
    channel.close()                       # channel is closed, but not the client
    return out, err, returncode

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname, username = user, password = pw)
out, err, rc = run_cmd(client, 'grep -i "Lost LLUS websocket" /var/log/debesys/cme.log')
# Do whatever with the output
# Run any other commands
client.close()
```

Of course, there's a number of other options. You could scp the file to the local machine, open it in python, and search on it. You could even cat the file with an ssh call and use python search on the output.